# Set route's Order precedence in Minimal APIs using RouteEndpointBuilder ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I am trying to set order of Routes (with same path : `api/v1/users` ) defined in minimal APIs using app.Map(..) by giving Order to both definitions so that at a time only one is used

i am using followinfg code:

```
    var endPt1 = new RouteEndpointBuilder(emptyDelegate, RoutePatternFactory.Parse("/api/v1/users"), 1);
    app.Map(endPt1.RoutePattern, getUser1);

    var endPt2 = new RouteEndpointBuilder(emptyDelegate, RoutePatternFactory.Parse("/api/v1/users"),2);
    app.Map(endPt2.RoutePattern, getUser2);
```

In `RoutePattern.InboundPrecedence` the value is same in both endPt1, endPt2.

How can i set order correctly so that at a time with same path, only one route is called with lower order Precedence?

Repo link: [Code Link on github](https://github.com/sanasz91mdev/.net6App)
Path: \AppNet6\Modules

Answer (score 0):

Configure the EndpointBuilder via a convention can resolve this:

app.Map("/api/v1/users", emptyDelegate).Add(static builder => ((RouteEndpointBuilder)builder).Order = 1)